# iOS: On not duplicating the view hierarchy in the MVC model

Tags: ios, objective-c, model-view-controller

This question is related to *MVC* (in iOS programming),  and to a book wherein the author uses MVC somewhat *differently* from what I have seen before.

I think I have a pretty clear understanding of Apple's interpretation of the MVC-pattern, as it is explained in Stanford's on-line course on iOS programming. That is to say, the *Model* and the *View* should be *independent*, and the *Controller* should act as the glue in between.

I have implemented a few iOS applications where the view contains *movable objects*. In doing so, the movable objects have been implemented as Sub-views (or CALayer:s), and they have been instantiated by the main view. A sub-view knows its own location and size (in the frame property), but that information is often *duplicated* in my model object. In fact, the entire view hierarchy is often represented in the model (and I blame much of my *spagetti* coding to this *redundancy*).

In the book *Beginning iOS Game Development* the author, *Patrick Alessi*, implements a  game called blocked (a.k.a breakout). In his implementation, *the model allocates and initializes an array of UIView objects* (the blocks in the breakout game) and the controller then adds them to the view. When a block later on should disappear, the model removes it from the superview as well as from the array.

I have mixed feelings of Alessi's implementation. It avoids the duplication of data! But how does it relate to MVC? I ask this question to broaden my own understanding of MVC. Is it  possible to regard an UIView object as both a view and as a model object?

Answer (score 1):

Well it's a game not an information processing application. The model is really closely tied to the view because you care about where on screen the blocks are so you can calculate if they are being hit and so on. Same goes for 3D shooters where most information concerns things that have a location somewhere in 3D space. Just make sure that you manage to refactor out most code that doesn't directly involve drawing the View out of the UIView subclass.

Things like scoring, player data and ads should use the traditional MVC model.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty common for an app to have a representation of each model object in the view hierarchy.

As you say, the glue belongs in the controller. If I were writing the breakout game, I would put the logic to create the array of view objects in the controller.

In a game app it might make sense to stretch or even abandon the MVC design pattern. The model object (a brick) could be a view object at the same time. The controller would manage an array of bricks directly, where that management would involve updating the coordinates of the bricks, their onscreen/offscreen status, etc. That's probably how I would tackle a game like that.

Answer (score 1):

SmallTalk was initially considered model-view, with the controller role evolving naturally before Objective-C's welding of that language to C. I think there's correspondingly an extent to which you can view the controller as being a little less concrete in purpose; certainly it's to provide some abstraction between the two components but therefore the general of avoiding redundant abstractions has to apply.

Extreme example: your model object is an `NSString`. You want to be able to put strings on screen. You've got the code to render an individual character; that's obviously a view thing. The `NSString` can vend a list of its characters; that's obviously a model thing. Do you really need a formal, separate controller class to spoon feed the characters one by one to a view or views? Is it helpful to have one?

I think most people therefore allow scenarios where a view can render, in its entirety, a model object, even if it's a much more complicated compound than a string. Suppose you had an address book object which compounded a name and a phone number. Most people would allow a view to receive that object and compose subviews for display internally. Often that will mean the view talking directly to the model and possibly the model doing some work for the view — if the view needs the phone number then why should it care whether that property is implemented as `@dynamic`? If the model evolves from a standard stored property to something that requires a more complicated lookup, why should that implicate changes to the view?

The controller then becomes responsible primarily for composing the complete interface. It glues together the constituent parts to allow collections of renderable objects to form a coherent display.

Like you I would have severe misgivings about Alessi permitting a model directly to manipulate a view hierarchy. The model should absolutely not involve itself in view stuff. The onus should be on views to display model stuff, with the controller decoupling where a decoupling makes sense.